# Dog licks - kashrut status of dog saliva?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals

What is the kashrut status of dog* saliva? This question is about what regularly eating treif does to the kashrut status of their saliva.

<sup>*(or any animal that eats treif or other unkosher food)</sup>

Comment: As opposed to human saliva?

Comment: @shmosel no, lav davka lol. The question is because they regularly eat treif, so what is the kashrut status of their saliva

Comment: Probably the same as dog milk

Comment: @DoubleAA Milk is food. Does saliva even fall into that category?

Comment: @RabbiKaii is the salient principle at work here the fact that they eat non-kosher, or that they themselves are non-kosher? I would assume the latter, no?

Comment: @יהושעק the former, but the latter would override the former if true and make the question less interesting, and warrant a question about human saliva. Meir's answer is interesting. +1 for "salient"

Comment: @shmosel eg Igros Moshe, YD 2:24?

Comment: The question is whether saliva is considered יוצא מן הטמא. The Tosefta in Bechoros says that דבש זוזין is forbidden because it is ריר, which generally means saliva. This would imply that saliva is forbidden as yotzei; however, the Gemara in Bechoros records that דבש גזין is permitted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We find that dough (or bread) into which a dog bit remains tahor, unless there are grounds for assuming that the dog had touched the food with tamei liquids in its mouth. Its saliva getting on the food doesn't make a difference, though (Mishnah, Taharos 3:8).

The implication would seem to be that the food is kosher, then (otherwise the only difference as to whether it's tamei or tahor would be as far as its touching other foods, and one would expect such a detail to be noted - if not in the Mishnah, then at least in Rambam's formulation of this halachah in Hil. She'ar Avos Hatum'os 16:4).

Similarly, the Gemara (Horios 13b) warns that eating food that had been munched on by a mouse or a cat is bad for one's memory, but doesn't say anything about it being forbidden to eat, even though those are also both non-kosher animals that regularly eat treif foods.

Comment: Presumably the reason would be because the saliva isn't considered "food"

Comment: @AKA the reason for what?

Comment: @RabbiKaii IIUC, the reason why "saliva getting on the food doesn't make a difference". If it were, it would.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @AKA what makes you presume that?

Comment: Should have said "I'd guess"